# R Merging with Duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

My data consists of Part Numbers with the date of sale expressed by Year, Month, Quarter, Day.  The same part could be sold on the same day but with a different invoice number so there are duplicate part numbers per day.  The data looks similar to below:

```
Year <- c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018)
Month <- c("Aug", "Sep", "Sep", "Aug", "Sep", "Aug", "Sep")
Day <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
Revenue <- c(147, 200, 250, 300, 200, 250, 150)
PartNumber <- c("1234", "5678", "5678", "1234", "5678", "5678", "9101")

testdf <- data.frame(Year, Month, Day, Revenue, PartNumber)
> testdf
  Year Month Day Revenue PartNumber
1 2016   Aug   1     147       1234
2 2016   Sep   2     200       5678
3 2016   Sep   2     250       5678
4 2017   Aug   1     300       1234
5 2017   Sep   2     200       5678
6 2018   Aug   1     250       5678
7 2018   Sep   2     150       9101
```

What I have been doing is making a new data frame and adding one to the Year column and then naming the Revenue column as Revenue Last Year like below:

```
testdfCopy <- testdf
testdfCopy$Year <- testdfCopy$Year + 1
colnames(testdfCopy)[4] <- "RevenueLY"
mergeddf <- merge(testdf, testdfCopy, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "PartNumber"), all = TRUE)
```

Then when I merge them, I take the sums of the first data frame Revenue and the merged data frame Revenue but they turn out differently of course, so I am looking for a way to fix this problem.  My actual data consists of millions of rows so hopefully we can find a way that isn't manual or time consuming.

```
> sum(testdf$Revenue)
[1] 1497
> sum(mergeddf$Revenue, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1697
```

In the end I get mergeddf:

```
> mergeddf
   Year Month Day PartNumber Revenue RevenueLY
1  2016   Aug   1       1234     147        NA
2  2016   Sep   2       5678     200        NA
3  2016   Sep   2       5678     250        NA
4  2017   Aug   1       1234     300       147
5  2017   Sep   2       5678     200       200
6  2017   Sep   2       5678     200       250
7  2018   Aug   1       1234      NA       300
8  2018   Aug   1       5678     250        NA
9  2018   Sep   2       5678      NA       200
10 2018   Sep   2       9101     150        NA
11 2019   Aug   1       5678      NA       250
12 2019   Sep   2       9101      NA       150
```

But I want:

```
> finaldf
  Year Month Day Revenue PartNumber RevenueLY
1 2016   Aug   1     147       1234        NA
2 2016   Sep   2     200       5678        NA
3 2016   Sep   2     250       5678        NA
4 2017   Aug   1     300       1234       147
5 2017   Sep   2     200       5678       200
6 2018   Aug   1     250       5678        NA
7 2018   Sep   2     150       9101        NA
```

Comment: I think the real question here is, "what do you want the result to be?".  My suggestion would be to keep one dataframe (like the one you have) of actual sales.  And to create another dataframe that contains the aggregated sales to the day (or month, or year, or whatever is of interest to you).  Then, only with this aggregated dataframe would it make sense to do things like make a column of last-year's revenue.

Comment: Sorry Dan Y,  I posted an edit of the desired data frame outcome.

Comment: I got you.  So maybe you just need to create an order number within a month-year, then you can merge by month-year-ordernum.  I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is dplyr possible option (create index for joining tables and using left_join):

```
   library(dplyr)
   testdf <- testdf%>%
    mutate(ind=paste0(Year, Month, Day), NextYear= Year+1, ind_next=paste0(NextYear, Month, Day))

    testdf%>%
    left_join(testdf[,c(4,6)], by=c("ind_next"="ind"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I think you're looking for this:

```
# use data.table
    library(data.table)
    setDT(testdf)

# create an ordernum so that the revenue from the first sale of part A in 
# month M and year Y will be  matched to the first sale of part A in month  
# M and year Y+1  -- as requested by the OP
    testdf[ , ordernum := 1:.N, by=.(Year, Month, PartNumber)]

# use your approach of copy, adjust year, rename-revenue
    testdfCopy <- copy(testdf)
    testdfCopy[ , Year := Year + 1]
    testdfCopy[ , RevenueLY := Revenue]

# merge
    mergeddf <- merge(testdf, 
                  testdfCopy[ , .(Year, Month, ordernum, PartNumber, RevenueLY)], 
                  by=c("Year", "Month", "PartNumber", "ordernum"), 
                  all.x=TRUE)
```